# How to customize PropertyMapper implementing PropertyMapperInterface Kentico Kontent PHP SDK?

Tags: php, laravel, kentico-kontent

I'm trying to reformat the key name, I don't want camelCase key returned. So I commented out this code in the getProperty function.
`$arrKey = TextHelper::getInstance()->camelCase($arrKey);`
However I can't figure out how to do it
[implements Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNORH.png)

```
$client = new DeliveryClient($this->projectID, $this->previewKey);
$client->propertyMapper = new CustomPropertyMapper();
```

I tried implementing this way, however I get null result.
I tried updating directly in vendor and it worked.
However since I need to check some conditions to apply this I have to find a way to implement it when the condition is true.
Is it possible to implement this?